# Why must shared libraries be position independent while static libraries don't?

Tags: c, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I understand position independent code uses offsets from the current position whilst position dependent code uses absolute addresses.

However, I don't understand why shared libraries must be treated as being position independent whilst static libraries do not?

Comment: Imagine you have two dynamic libraries, with overlapping memory addresses. Now a program tries to use (and consequently load) both of them.

Comment: @EOF Whats meant by overlapping memory addresses?

Comment: The sets of memory addresses used by the libraries are not (pairwise) disjoint. IOW, there exist (non-empty) pairwise intersections between the sets.

Comment: @EOF I apologise however I am struggling to understand what is meant by disjoint memory addresses.

Comment: If `libA` uses memory at address `0x20000` to store code ot data, and `libB` uses memory at address `0x20000` to store *other code or data*, that's not going to work.

Comment: Why would this happen in the first place with shared libraries?

Comment: Remember that much of the current practice in computing comes from times of 32- or even 16-bit computing. Imagine for simplicity that you partition the 32-bit address space into 1 MiB chunks, of which each library will get one. Not you have 4096 distinct "library chunks". Add the birthday paradox and 10s-100s of thousand libraries to choose from, and you see that fixing the addresses of dynamic libraries doesn't work. For 64-bit address space you might even get away with it, but at the same time 64-bit processor architectures tend to include features that make PIC less painful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, nowadays programs have only one linear address-space for everything, backed by virtual memory (hardware and os subsystem). And everything used must be fitted into it somehow.

For that, we have to differentiate between PIC code (any position is good), relocatable code (one position is preferred), and fixed code (only one position works).

As the executable itself is priviliged, in that it is the first user code loaded (aside from a loader in some systems, though that can generally reposition itself seamlessly), it can be put wherever you want. Using that limits ASLR though.

Code in static libraries for executables can take advantage, though will limit the including code.

The order in which the shared libraries are loaded on the other hand is far less well-specified, thus while the loader can try to put it at a preferred position, it generally has to be able to put it elsewhere.
Thus, shared libraries, and code for inclusion by them, has to be PIC or at least relocatable.

PIC code is generally slightly slower, though needs fewer fixups, meaning most can be reloaded from the source-binary as needed, instead of having to be either re-relocated (which happened in Windows 95 and descendents) or swapped to disk when the space is needed.

Comment: Would it be correct to say that because we do not know where a shared library will be loaded into memory, we must ensure it is position independent code?

Comment: Yes. Though we can *sometimes* get away with guessing. Are you feeling lucky today?

Comment: But why not use relocation instead of pic? Btw was that a dirty harry reference

Comment: @duper21 As I said, PIC needs far fewer fixups (and those concentrated in a few pages) than relocatable code (and those are pretty evenly distributed everywhere). Thus, nearly all the relocatable code is localized to each single process it is used in, while PIC code shares nearly everything as it isn't touched, aside from a page or two.

Comment: @Deduplicator Relevant username?

Answer (score 1):

Actually "static libraries" have position independent code, too. The difference is that the linker resolves those relative addresses to absolute addresses when building the static executable.  Once the static library is linked, it cannot be executed at any other address.

For shared libraries to be able to be shared it means the code most not be changed. Therefore the code is prepared to work at any position at run-time.

All "addresses" used above mean "virtual addresses" there days. Static libraries still can be loaded and executed at different physical addresses while the virtual addresses stay the same...